# UIApplicationDelegate not called when using Backgrounder on a jailbroken device

Tags: iphone, background, jailbreak, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm running into a bit of an issue.
My software needs to know when the application is in background so it will disconnect from the server, and start receiving push notifications.

For that I use UIApplicationDelegate's method :

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

The problem is, when a jailbroken device is using the "tweak" called backgrounder, that will force your application to stay active and not going into background, none of the UIApplicationDelegate's method get called when we click on the HOME button.

The thing is, each client connected in SSL cost me a lot of memory on the server. I do not really care that the device is jailbroken, or as a matter a fact, the application will run indefinitely on the device. But I would like them to disconnect from the server when the application is no longer on the screen, but I can't seems to find any method that will inform me of such operation when backgrounder is installed.

**Solution find** : [check my own answer on the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11034826/374215)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Milk Tea got me on the right track... So the bounty goes to him.

But actually I got a better solution...
I have checked every single notifications thrown when resigning the App...

and I got this, even with backgrounder configured to keep the App open, those notifications are thrown :

```
UIApplicationSuspendedEventsOnlyNotification -- When going into background
UIApplicationResumedEventsOnlyNotification   -- When going into foreground
```

This makes sense, since even with backgrounder, it would have been a bad idea to let the App keep receiving events notifications, for example, when a change of rotation (or a shake) is done outside the App. Do you imagine every App doing a rotation on background everytime you move your iphone ?

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do would to eat up A LOT of memory so that way the jail breakers would have to quit your application! Just kidding of course. The best option is to wait for inactivity on the user's side. For example: 1. Check if the device is jailbroken. 2. Check if backgrounder is installed (I am not sure if you can do this but I am pretty sure you can). 3. If the user is all those things wait for them to be inactive for, lets say, 30 seconds and then disconnect from the server.

Comment: I'm really considering the first idea ;-) However, I though about you third solution which seems the easier right now, only that, if the application is on screen, I would like to stay connected. An user may have reasons to let the application open on the screen, if so, it should stay connected. If I put a timer that will disconnect the user even if the application is on screen, that's not an option, unfortunately !

Comment: It seems that there no other solutions... I'll disconnected the user after a certain amount of time, if there was no interaction (any touch on the screen) for a while...

Answer (score 1):

Do none of those methods get called at all in your app when Backgrounder is installed, or only when your app transitions to the background? If they never get called at all, then the solution is extremely simple: Set a timer for, say, 10 seconds, when your app's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is called, and when that timer expires, if `applicationDidBecomeActive:` has not been called, then you know that the user is using Backgrounder.

If they do get called on app launch, though, then things get trickier. I'm not aware of any direct methods to detect if a tweak like Backgrounder is installed from within the sandbox. You could simply check if the device is jailbroken (there are a number of ways to do this, they should be easy to find), and add a timeout period for your server connection if so.

Comment: Unfortunately, they do get called at launch... only on transition to the background, they are caught somewhere and not distributed to the App... About the second part, If the device is jailbroken, it doesn't mean that backgrounder is present and configured to keep the App open.

Comment: Ah that's too bad. I know that a jailbroken device doesn't necessarily mean they have Backgrounder installed, but my point is that it might be a suitable compromise, at least to filter your user base down to those who might actually have Backgrounder installed. Alternatively, you could try working with your `UIWindow` and listening for notifications like `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification` - it's possible that Backgrounder implicitly causes the application's window to hide when transitioning to the background.

Comment: Oh whoops, I saw you have an actual solution now. Nice :)

Comment: +1. Thank you for your answer and follow-up ! Yeah I found out a solution when I was looing for a way to check for touch event within the App, I have tracked this notification. Seems it is a good solution, even If now I have to carry around a BOOL property to know if the app is in background or not, but that's a small price to pay, in order to gain a lot of memory on the server ;-)